# How can I slice a dataframe into multiple, and stitch it back together in a tuple without hardcoding

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am slicing a dataframe by identifier column and creating subset dataframes using for loop and globals(). And finally I combine all the sliced dataframes into a tuple. As you can see, the tuple creating part is manual, but I need to expand my code to a much larger dataset, and can't do it manually, and wanted to add this step to my for loop to have **tup** in one step without me needing to type "tup = (TT_a,TT_b,TT_c,TT_d,TT_e)". I just need the output, so please suggest any way to achieve it, do not need to use globals()

```
#creates dataframe
import pandas as pd
loc = [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000]
identifier = ['a','a','a','a','b','b','c','d','e','f']
d = {'loc':loc,'identifier':identifier}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)


#create sliced dataframe by identifier, 6 unique
for i in df['identifier'].unique():
    globals()['TT_%s' % i] = df[df['identifier'] == i].reset_index()[['loc','identifier']]
```

> %who
>
> ```
> TT_a   TT_b    TT_c    TT_d    TT_e    TT_f    d   df  i   
> identifier     loc     pd
> ```

```
#Final Output needed
tup = (TT_a,TT_b,TT_c,TT_d,TT_e)
```

Comment: @anky_91 with the current for loop, after it executes it creates TT_ + identifier and creates multiple dataframes by the identifier value. And running a magic command %who I can see those 6 dfs created, and my final step is I type all of their names and encapsulate them in parenthesis to create a tuple containing all of them. The problem is that I need to expand this to a larger dataset, so won't be able to type them in to create the final tuple.

Comment: Can't you just collect the sub-dataframes in a list, without giving them individual names?  `alist.append(...)` is a dandy way of building a list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please do not use `globals` like that...

Use dictionary:

```
d={}
for i in df['identifier'].unique():
    if len(df.loc[df['identifier'] == i,'identifier']) > 1:
        d['TT_%s' % i] = df.loc[df['identifier'] == i, ['loc','identifier']].reset_index()
```